# Split the string into lines from the nth delimiter as the title of the plot

Tags: python-3.x, string, matplotlib

For the dictionary `d`, I extracted the combination of key-value pairs as the title of matplotlib plot, but assuming that string `res` is too long, I want to split `res` from the second comma into two lines as the title of the plot, how should I do it? Thanks.

```
d = {'lag(0)_pred': 0.83,
'lag(1)_pred': 0.51,
'lag(2)_pred': 0.17,
'lag(3)_pred': 0.52
}

out = [f'{key}: {d[key]:.2f}' for key in d]
res = ", ".join(out)
res
```

Out:

```
'lag(0)_pred: 0.83, lag(1)_pred: 0.51, lag(2)_pred: 0.17, lag(3)_pred: 0.52'
```

Code of the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.plot(x, y)
# set title
plt.title(f"{res}", loc='center', wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

The expected result:

[image]

Comment: `res = ", ".join(out[:2]) + "\n" + ", ".join(out[2:])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code following works:

***Option 1:***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2
groups = res.split(', ')
result = ', '.join(groups[:n]), ', '.join(groups[n:])

x = [1, 2, 3, 9]
y = [4, 5, 6, 9]
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.plot(x, y)
# set title
plt.title(f"{result[0]}\n{result[1]}", loc='center', wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

***Option 2:***

```
import re

n = 1
occerence = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(', ', res)]
result = [res[:occerence[n]], res[occerence[n]+1:]]
result

x = [1, 2, 3, 9]
y = [4, 5, 6, 9]
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.plot(x, y)
# set title
plt.title(f"{result[0]}\n{result[1]}", loc='center', wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

***Option 3, best and simplest solution provided by @JohanC:***

```
d = {'lag(0)_pred': 0.83, 
'lag(1)_pred': 0.51, 
'lag(2)_pred': 0.17, 
'lag(3)_pred': 0.52
}

out = [f'{key}: {d[key]:.2f}' for key in d]
res = ", ".join(out[:2]) + "\n" + ", ".join(out[2:])

x = [1, 2, 3, 9]
y = [4, 5, 6, 9]
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.plot(x, y)
# set title
plt.title(f"{res}", loc='center', wrap=True)
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]